# Git merge from someone else's fork

Tags: git, github, git-branch

I have a repository on github, and someone else has forked it and made changes.

I want to:

1. Create a new branch
2. Merge their changes into my branch

I have created the new branch:

```
git commit -b my_new_branch
```

How do I merge their code into this new branch?

This is the branch that I have created: https://github.com/poundifdef/VirginMobileMinutesChecker/tree/widget_toast

This is the branch that I want to merge:
https://github.com/xbakesx/VirginMobileMinutesChecker

What is the best way to do this? I've tried a "pull" and it won't work. I honestly have no idea what I'm doing in gitland, so if there is a better way to accomplish this (besides my creating a branch and trying to merge) then I am all ears!

Comment: You've got an typo/error in your command to create the branch. It's `git checkout -b my_new_branch` not `git commit -b my_new_branch`. Creating a branch does *not* create a commit.

Answer (score 125, accepted):

Add their github fork repo as a remote to a clone of your own repo:

```
git remote add other-guys-repo <url to other guys repo>
```

Get their changes:

```
git fetch other-guys-repo
```

Checkout the branch where you want to merge:

```
git checkout my_new_branch
```

Merge their changes in (assuming they did their work on the master branch):

```
git merge other-guys-repo/master
```

Resolve conflicts, commit the resolutions and voila.

Comment: Git is no less than impenetrable to me. Thank you so much!

Comment: Use it, every single day. You'll learn and soon it'll be indispensable instead :)

Comment: Don't forget to use "git checkout -b my_new_branch" if it doesn't already exist

Comment: @Ian no need - once you have done a fetch, git will automatically create a new branch with the same name when you do checkout and it finds a branch with that name

Comment: What should I do after my merge request to the main repo is done and I want to update my fork?

Comment: @jeraldo you can most likely just pull from their repo.