# Updating forked repo from upstream develop branch? (Not something we can merge)

Tags: git, github, git-merge

[Edit #2]: adding new details

Hi all - have been doing a good amount of research on this but haven't found something that matches my situation.

I'm following the process here to keep a fork updated: there are a lot of resources online about keeping my fork updated if their changes are on their `master` branch, e.g. [Git merge from someone else's fork](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5606048/git-merge-from-someone-elses-fork)

Here's the process I'm following.

[inside local directory for given repo]

`git remote add origin [link]; git remote add upstream [link]`

`git fetch upstream`

`git checkout master`

`git merge --no-ff upstream/master`

My attempt to `merge` gives me `--no-ff - not something we can merge` which is a tough error to decode!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only thing I could see missing is an update to the `master` branch before the `merge --no-ff`

```
git checkout master
git pull
```

Just to make sure master itself is up-to-date.

The [OP AmeySMahajan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12071288/ameysmahajan)  added [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57947741/updating-forked-repo-from-upstream-develop-branch-not-something-we-can-merge/57950666#comment102369125_57950666):

> Incorporated `git checkout master` then `git pull upstream master` and then the merge line, but still getting `merge: --no-ff - not something we can merge`, unfortunately.

But: A `pull` is a `fetch`+`merge`, so an *additional* `merge` (`--no-ff` or not) of `upstream/master`, which you *already* pulled, would not do anything. –

Comment: Incorporated `git checkout master` then `git pull upstream master` and then the `merge` line, but still getting `merge: --no-ff - not something we can merge`, unfortunately.

Comment: @AmeySMahajan A `pull` is a `fetch`+`merge`, so an *additional* `merge` (`--no-ff` or not) of `upstream/master`, which you *already* pulled, would not do anything.

Comment: I think that's the issue, thanks very much! Do you want to add that to your answer above?