# Git: How to push to someone's fork?

Tags: git, github, gitlab

I work for an open-source project and forked it already. Someone has forked it too and has been working with some interesting ideas which won't be pushed to origin soon. I want to help him thus I cloned his fork to my computer. However, I can't push directly my work to his fork. I can't fork him either since I have a fork from origin already. What should I do? Thanks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/28119733/7976758, https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgithub%5D+create+second+fork

Comment: Add the forked repo as another remote to your local repositry, fetch the changes from that remote, rebase the work you want to send onto the fork's work, then push your changes to the other remote (or send a PR).

Comment: @JeffMercado : can you add an answer with all necessary git commands? Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Suppose your repository looked like this:

[image]

```sh
#Add the forked repo as another remote to your local repository
git remote add someone https://fork.url                 #create remote called "someone"

#fetch the changes from that remote
git fetch someone
```

[image]

```sh
#rebase the work you want to send onto the fork's work
git branch for-someone my-branch                        #create branch "for-someone" at "my-branch"
git rebase master for-someone --onto someone/master     #take commits from the "for-someone" branch down to your "master" branch and rebase it onto someone's "master" branch
```

[image]

```sh
#then push your changes to the other remote
git push someone for-someone                            #push branch "for-someone" to the "someone" remote
```

Insert more appropriate remote and branch names.

Comment: BTW, if you just want to commit a small thing/push to a PR/contributors fork/branch, you can omit the `git remote add` step and just use the URL of the fork (in this example `https://fork.url`) as the origin.

I.e. just do: `git push https://fork.url for-someone` works too. (At least in recent git versions.)

Answer (score 0):

You can do the two things as @jeff-mercado mentioned. This will be a complex task and I would advise you to use a GUI based git client for this. I have faced the same problem as you faced and found [Sublime Merge](https://www.sublimemerge.com/download) to be very useful.

I would suggest asking him to send you a PR.
Then you will be able to merge his changes into your repository
Finally you can push the merged repo on your github and ask him to clone it and push.
(This is assuming the other guy won't do the work of merging your PR, which will be easier for you.)

Comment: Look like the scenario you mentioned is not my current one. There is the main repo, his fork and I (the 3rd person) want to contribute to his fork, not the main repo, not my repo. I want to make a PR to his repo.

Comment: This link might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5606048/git-merge-from-someone-elses-fork

Comment: No, that doesn't help since it is about only 2 people, and merging from 2nd person to the 1st one